# Proof for antisymmetric tensor and vector

Tags: tensors

I got the anti-symmetric tensor $C_{ij}$   and a vector $w_i=\epsilon_{ijk} C_{jk}$

I want to proof that $C_{mq}=\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{mqi}w_i.$

Answer (score 0):

To prove this, you need the following identity
$$
\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ilh}=\delta_{jl}\delta_{kh}-\delta_{jh}\delta_{kl},\qquad\forall j,k,l,h\in\{1,2,3\}
$$
where there is an implicit sum over the repeated index $i.$

So, starting from
$$
w_i = \varepsilon_{ijk}C_{jk}
$$
let's multiply both sides by $\varepsilon_{ilh}$ and sum over $i$
$$
\varepsilon_{ilh}w_i = \varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{ilh}C_{jk}
$$
now, using the previous identity on the RHS
$$
\varepsilon_{ilh}w_i = (\delta_{jl}\delta_{kh}-\delta_{jh}\delta_{kl})C_{jk}=C_{lh}-C_{hl}=2C_{lh}
$$
then
$$
C_{lh}=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{ilh}w_i=\frac{1}{2}\varepsilon_{lhi}w_i
$$